# Parallax Effect with static points?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an idea I want to implement for a project.

There is a section of the page that will utilise the parallax effect similar to here:

http://stephband.info/jparallax/

With some differences:

1. The parallax area will be full width and utilise photography rather than vector imagery;
2. I want to place fixed tool-tip areas that a user can over over and be given more info.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

I have been looking at various tutorials and know the basics of how parallax works; the main stumbling block I can see is getting the tool-top hover areas to be static the specific layer they refer too and also follow the mouse for the parallax effect so that they remain in the correct area.

Comment: what you want done is possible. you will have to implement it on your own though as there exists no ready made code

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking a little bit? Are you trying to keep the tooltips attached to the mouse, or attached to the parallax layer that creates them?

Comment: Imagine a room scene, 3 layers: foreground, furniture, background.

If a tooltip is attached to a piece of furniture, assuming the parallax is mouse activated the tooltip would need to move with the layer in the correct place.